# Question concerning the proof of Theorem 20.16 in Lee‘s Introduction to smooth manifolds (Fundamental Theorem on Lie Algebra Actions)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Theorem 20.16 of his Introduction to smooth manifolds Lee proves that every complete Lie($G$)-action $\hat{\theta}:Lie(G)\to \Gamma (TM),$ where $G$ is a simply connected Lie group, is the infinitesimal generator of some smooth right $G$-action on $M.$

I‘ll quickly outline the idea of proof until the point where I am stuck:

Writing $\hat{X}$ for $\hat{\theta}(X)$ he defines for each $X\in Lie(G)$ a new vector field $\tilde{X}_{(g,p)}=(X_g,\hat{X}_p).$ 
He then goes on to define a distribution $D$ pointwise by declaring $D_{(g,p)}$ to be the set of all vectors $\tilde{X}_{(g,p)}$ as $X$ ranges over $Lie(G)$. He then shows that this distribution is involutive and so for each $p\in M$ he defines $S_p$ to be the leaf of the induced foliation containing $(e,p).$
Furthermore he sets $\Pi_p:=\pi_G|_{S_p}$ and wants to show that this is a smooth covering map.
For each $q \in M$ such that $(g,q)\in \Pi_p^{-1}(g)$he defines a map $\sigma_q:V\to G\times M$ for a certain nbhd $V$ of $g$ and he showes that these are smooth local sections.

This is the point where I‘m missing something:

How do we know that there exist such a $q$? Or put differently, why is $\Pi_p:S_p\to G$ surjective? Except from this, everything else is clear to me.

I‘d be glad for explanations or hints in the right direction (maybe I have to read between the lines).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: first, take a neighborhood $U$ of $e$ in $G$ that is contained in the image of $\Pi_p$, then Lee's argument implies that for each $g$ in $U$, we can construct a local section for $\Pi_p$ on $gU$, in particular, $gU$ is in the image of $\Pi_p$.